# Passbook: Couldn't find a passTypeIdentifier in the pass?

Tags: ios, passbook

I followed all steps as per Apple recommendations to create a passbook but whenever I use the signpass tool (provided by apple) to sign the pass package I get "Couldn't find a passTypeIdentifier in the pass" Any thoughts on what could be the problem? Spent my weekend on this! thank you

Answer (score 5):

When **signpass** tries to compile an invalid pass.json file multiple errors occur.
The first error returned is "Couldn't find a passTypeIdentifier in the pass".
This error can be displayed even if there is nothing wrong with your passTypeIdentifier.

Check your pass.json file for syntax errors at [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com).

Common errors:

- forgetting to add a comma at the end of a line
- adding an extra comma after last set of curly brackets